# Double Entry Accounting in C/C++/Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I am working on a program and need to implement a double-entry accounting system.  It would seem to me that there should be some open source project or code base out there already with most all of the basic accounting functions already written, but Google didn't turn anything up.

I don't want to re-invent the wheel, so is anyone aware if there is already a package out there that implements double-entry accounting in C, C++, or Objective-C?

Thank you!

(Frank)

**Note: I am looking for a double-entry module to plug in to my existing application (it is a property management system) and I'm not re-writing a package like GNUCash. Sorry if I didn't state that clearly.**

Comment: Under what licence are you planning to distribute your software?  This is important because if somebody recommends a module licensed as (say) GPL v3, you'll find you may be obliged to distribute your software under the same terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GnuCash - http://www.gnucash.org/

Comment: I am looking for a double-entry module to plug in to my existing application (it is a property management system) and I'm not re-writing a package like GNUCash. Sorry if I didn't state that clearly

Comment: believe it is plugable through bonobo.

Answer (score 2):

[GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) is open source and I believe large parts of the backend are in `C`

Answer (score 0):

Ledger - http://ledger-cli.org/

It's a pure C++ command-line engine for double-entry accounting. It follows the Unix philosophy so you don't actually even need to delve into the code--just parse the plain text output.